# How make a "ValueError" exception replace an item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am trying to write a piece of code that will go through a list of numbers (splitting on vertical bars) that if the user enters a non number, will throw an exception and replace said object with 0. It is intended to display the list in descending order (largest to smallest) with vertical bars in between.
This is my code currently, but I cannot get it to work.

```
    numbers = input("Please enter several integer numbers separated by 
    vertical bars. ").split('|')
    for item in numbers:
        try:
            numbers = [int(item) for item in numbers]
        except ValueError:
            item = item.replace(item,'0')
    numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse = True)
    print(' | '.join(str(num) for num in numbers))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
numbers = input("Please enter several integer numbers separated by vertical bars. ")
numbers = numbers.split('|')
temp = []
for item in numbers:
    try:
        temp.append(int(item))
    except ValueError:
        temp.append(0)
numbers = temp
```

Note that here we don't change `numbers` while we're iterating over it. Another way to accomplish the same task would be something like

```
def eval_number(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

numbers = input("Please enter several integer numbers separated by vertical bars. ")
numbers = numbers.split('|')
numbers = list(map(eval_number, numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for something like this:

```
fixed_numbers=[]
for n in numbers:
try:
    fixed_numbers.append(int(n))
except ValueError:
    fixed_numbers.append(0)
```

Doing list comprehension in the try block will kick out to the except block and you have no way to go back and finish the list.  For example:

```
try:
    numbers = [int(n) for index, n in enumerate(numbers)]
except ValueError:
    numbers[index] = 0
```

works, for the first non integer value in numbers, only

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually replace the elements in the list you need to assign to the indexed element.

I'd separate the manipulating function and the replacement loop:

```
def int_or_zero(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int_or_zero(numbers[i])
```